# SPI signal integrity issue

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, spi, signal-integrity

I have a custom four-layer PCB (Signal, Ground, Power, Signal) with an STM32F4 (72 MHz) connected to a Si4684 receiver and a Si4711 FM transmitter through SPI.

[image]

It seems that my design has some signal integrity issues. I can communicate with the Si4711, but I can only communicate short commands with the Si4684. Communication with Si4684 fails (some bits are incorrect) when transferring the firmware image from the STM32 to the chip (large data transfer).

When I connect my logic analyzer to the Si4711 MISO pin, this turns around. No communication is possible with the Si4711, but communication with Si4684 works flawlessly. If I connect the logic analyzer to the Si4711 MISO pin and send the POWER_UP command to the Si4711, it seems like there is no reply from the chip. Probing at the Si4711 MOSI pin clearly shows that the command is being received correctly.

The behavior is the same if I run the clock at 300 kHz or 8 MHz. Unfortunately I don't have a oscilloscope available, but I guess this could be a slew-rate-issue since it's independent of the clock.

What could be the reason that I need to connect the logic analyzer to the MISO pin to get the Si4684 working, and why does this make the Si4711 stop working?

What I've tried so far:
- Series termination (50 ohm, 100 ohm) on the CLK line
- Adjusting the GPIO speed of the SPI pins on the STM32 (LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH). I believe this sets the slew rate of the pin.
- Connecting the logic analyzer to the other SPI pins.
- Double checked that I have the correct SPI mode (0,0) set

I understand that I will have to make a new design, but I would very much like some input on why this happens.

Please find layout and partial schematic below. SCK, MOSI and MISO signals are highlighted.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: I moved the Si4711 to I²C instead, and now there are no issues.

Comment: You need chip enable signals for these SPI devices. In the question you did not mention anything about them.

Comment: Sorry, I kept the CS signals out of the drawing. But I have individual CS lines for each chip and I have confirmed that they are behaving correctly.

Comment: Can we see the pcb layout?

Comment: What is the power supply voltage of the STM32 ?
The Si4710 seems to be 2.7V to 5.5V compatible and the Si4684 is 1.8V chip.

Comment: FWIW I would not expect any issues with the layout you've described at the speeds you've described. Try to obtain an oscilloscope, it's really an essential tool.  The problem might be unrelated to the SPI. How is the power integrity and decoupling?  Agree that posting a full schematic and PCB layout would be helpful.

Comment: If you are using the wrong combination of modes, such that you are driving and sampling a given signal *on the same clock edge* rather than on opposite edges, very flaky operation could be expected, and parasitic loading of probes might fix/break things.

Comment: @kva Layout and schematic added

Comment: @pericynthion Yes, I really need a scope.. I've added the layout and partial schematics now.

Comment: @Foxrider83 The STM32 runs on 3.3v. The Si4684 has specified V IO to be 1.62 - 3.6v, so I think that should be ok.

Comment: You can limit the slew rate of the stm32 output pins in firmware, to see if that helps. If you don't know how, please say which dev platform you're using...

Comment: @bitsmack I thought that was done with the GPIO_SPEED property (LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, VERY_HIGH), but if this can be set some other place I'm eager to learn. I'm using openstm32 with the HAL driver.

Comment: Thanks, JohnDonut, but that was the setting I was referring to. I agree with the earlier comment that I wouldn't suspect signal integrity issues with your layout and speeds... I hope someone comes along with an answer that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. Yesterday I tried all sorts of termination, and I even tried to move the Si4711 to a different SPI bus (the same bus as the flash ic). Unfortunately nothing helped. So during the night I modified my board so that the Si4711 runs I2C instead. My worries are gone, everything works fine. But still curious why the SPI failed as it did..

Answer (score 1):

I worked on sensor-head (4 channel IR camera, CMOS mux under the IndiumPhosphide laminated sensor) that absolutely would not cooperate with the control-signal-emitting FPGA until I snipped all the digital interface wires (approx. 12 of them) and inserted 1Kohm resistors to greatly slow the edges of the timing signals and thus avoid undershoot (to -5 volts) and overshoot (to +10v) on the 0v/5v interface.

In diagnosing, before inserting the 1Kohm series Rs, I looked using a realtime TEK7904 (500MHz scope, no sampling done) and P6201 (900 MHz probe at 1pF when X10 head was slipped on), I saw these horrid overshoots with 500 picosecond edges running 4" across 1 PCB, another 4" across the 2nd PCB and then
running thru a 1" connector and down into the liquid nitrogen dewar.

We thus has 4+4" embedded inside PCB, with effective length of 8" (scaled by sqrt(Er)) thus 4+4 becomes 8+8, with return path making 16+16") plus connector and dewar.

Your SPI is only 3 wires. Explore where, exactly, the reflections/overshoots are best dampened.

Comment: I think that there is a conflict between those devices as he did not implement any chip select line, so both slaves try to communicate and using C language terminology it is an Undefined Behaviour :)

Comment: I have individual chip select lines and they are confirmed ok.

Comment: @PeterJ while there were no chip selects in the original "distance" diagram, the schematic since added shows them.